# Why is window.gapi.load() not working on Safari?

Tags: reactjs, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In in my React project via [gapi](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) library.

I deployed it on Netify, and it works on Chrome but doesn't work on Safari.

on Chrome:

[image]

on Safari:

[image]

Here is the source code and demo website.
[image]
[Github](https://github.com/mhsiungw/yt-app)

[Demo website](https://agitated-heyrovsky-cc2b05.netlify.app/)

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

update:

The reason it's not working in Safari is because I import the package in a wrong way.

I import the package using the following line of code in index.html.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

but it should be like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

I guess it's because of the race condition where the React component is rendered and cannot find the gapi package.